# How do I populate HTML content with new values once data has been changed on postback?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have `MVC3 razor` application. Once I'm submitting a form and in `Action` i'm changing `ViewModel` content, i can't see new values populated.

There was a topic about that in `MVC2` where guys told that it may be fixed in `MVC3` 
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/5089?ProjectName=aspnet

Can you tell if there is an option to do that or what is the better way(workaround) to update UI without JavaScript using postbacks?

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    model.Value = "new value"
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

UI:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Value)
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public string Value { get;set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's using the ModelState values that were posted.

If you clear the ModelState using `ModelState.Clear()` the new value you set should be in the hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `form` and to `post` it to action.

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Value)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Controller**

```
//
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Value = "old value";

    return View("Index", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    //get posted model values (changed value by view "new value")
    string changed_value = model.Value;

    // you can return model again if your model.State is false or after update
    return View("Index", model);
}
```